# How to find a document by data within an array of sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling to find the right syntax for my query.

I have the following schema

```
var Person = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    cars: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car'}] -- Note this is an array
});
```

I want to write a query that effectively tells me all the people that own a red car.

I think I want something like:

```
Person.find().populate('cars').match({colour:red}).exec(function(err, models) {....
```

But I can't find any documentation to back this up.  Any tips appreciated.

EDIT:

This code is getting close, but still no there

```
Person.find()
    .populate({path: 'cars', match: {colour: "red"}})
    .exec(function (err, Persons) {
```

The reason being, it returns all 'Person' records and only populates the 'cars' array for those it matches in the populate function.  As a result I get lots of Person.cars.length === 0 in there.

If I add a modification to the find:

```
Person.find()
    .populate({path: 'cars', match: {colour: "red"}})
    .where({'cars' : {$not: {$size:  0}}}
    .exec(function (err, Persons) {
```

This also has no affect; I'm assuming the where runs before the populate.  Breaking the query up into separate lines has no affect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , break it up in this manner

```
   var q = Person.find();
   q.populate('cars').match({color:red}).exec(function(err, models) {....}
```

or this , with thee same effect

```
      var q = Person.find();
   q.populate({path: 'cars', match: { color:red}}).exec(function(err, models) {....}
```

then you have to filter for whether car is present or not

like

```
.exec(function(err, models){
   models= docs.filter(function(model){
     return doc.cars.length;
   })
   // do stuff with models
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work.  I returns me all 'Person' records, and only populates 'cars' for the matching conditions.  For the other 'Person' records the 'cars' array is 0, but the 'Person' record is still in the results-set.

Comment: yes this will be like that you will have to maually filter than. like edited answer

Comment: Yep, that works - with a slightly neater filter structure than I was using, so thank you.  I was hoping to get an answer that managed all of that in the query rather than running a separate filter on the results-set, but at least this way I can proceed.  If I don't get a query-related answer in the next few days I'll accept this.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's typically more efficient to flip these type of queries around and first find the _ids of all the red cars and then find the people with those cars:

```
Car.find({colour: 'red'}, function(err, cars) {
    var carIds = cars.map(function(car) {
        return car._id;
    });
    Person.find({cars: {$in: carIds}}, function(err, persons) {...});
});
```

Comment: Cheers for that.  Another useful answer.